# Open WebView on item click in ActivityBar VSCode Extension API

Tags: webview, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The normal behavior is that clicks on an ActivityBar item open the treeview but what I need is to open the webview my extension gives me, I made the famous example app for vsc webviews called "Cat Typing" and I can open it with the Command Pallet command but is this somehow possible with click on my ActivityBar item?

Comment: this page https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/extending-workbench#view-container points to the azure app service extension as an extension that adds a view container to the activity bar.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azureappservice

Answer (score 0):

Of course! In `Explorer.ts` file you should write something like:

```
getTreeItem(element: Dependency): vscode.TreeItem {
  element.command = {
    command: "openWebviewCommand",
    title: "Open details",
    arguments: []
  };
  return element;
}
```

Then in `extension.ts`:

```
context.subscriptions.push(
  vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    'openWebviewCommand',
    () => new CatCoding(context)
  )
);
```